Why does PowerShell's Stop-Process -ProcessName explorer work, but command processor's taskkill not work for explorer.exe unless you use /f parameter?
Why does PowerShell's Stop-Process -ProcessName explorer (no -Force needed) work to terminate explorer.exe, but the command processor's taskkill command will not work to terminate explorer.exe unless you use the /f command line parameter with it?
I tested this on Windows 11.

Are you “just wondering this,” or is there actually a reason as to why are asking? A background? Not that it would matter, in fact, this is a really good question.
